# Scala/Akka pull pattern - manager receiving more work from workers

Tags: scala, design-patterns, akka

I am looking help with my hobby project. I am trying to find a better way how the Manager in my pull pattern will handle task list updates (list of work that needs to be done)

I have implemented a pull pattern where there is a Job Factory, Manager and a Worker. The Manager gets new jobs from the Job Factory with the help of akka scheduler. Whenever there is new work, Worker gets notified and it start chewing.

What might be a quirk in my implementation is that Worker spawns new tasks that have to be done as well. At the moment I have solved this with recursive messages from the Worker to itself.

Here is very simplistic idea of it:

```
class Worker extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Work0 ⇒ self ! Work1
    case Work1 ⇒ // ...
  }
}
```

However, I do not like this approach. I would like the already existing task list to be extended on the Manager side and let the worker send new jobs to Manager if new tasks should appear.

```
class Worker extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Work0 ⇒ Manager ! Work1
    case Work1 ⇒ // ...
  }
}
```

Here is a solution how to create a work buffer inside a Manager that is capable of dynamically changing. Whenever a Worker sends work to the Manager, it will be added on top of the buffer. Eventually Worker will loop through all the Tasks that manager has inside the buffer.

The example is without any plumbing for pull pattern itself, the idea was just to test how to get the buffer to work.

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer, ListBuffer}

class Manager extends Actor {
  var iterator: Iterator[Int] = Iterator.empty
  var buffer: Option[mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]] = None
  var iteratorCounter: Int = 0

  def receive = {
    case MyBuffer(workBuffer: mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]) ⇒
      buffer = Some(workBuffer)
      iterator = workBuffer.iterator
    case "iterate" ⇒
      if (iterator.hasNext) {
        iterator.next() // This will be sent to worker as a Task to process
        iteratorCounter += 1
      } else if (buffer.get.length > iteratorCounter) {
        iterator = buffer.get.iterator
        iterator = iterator.drop(iteratorCounter)
      } else {
        iteratorCounter = 0
      }
    case "add" ⇒ // "Worker adds" new stuff to Manager
      val random = scala.util.Random
      val newVal = random.nextInt(100)
      val append = (buf: Option[ArrayBuffer[Int]], element: Int) => Some(buf.get += element)
      buffer = append(buffer, newVal)

    case _ => println("huh?")
  }
}

case class MyBuffer(workBuffer: ArrayBuffer[Int])
val buffer = mutable.ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

val system = ActorSystem("PullPattern")
val helloActor = system.actorOf(Props(new Manager))
helloActor ! MyBuffer(buffer)
var a = 0

for (a <- 1 to 5) {
  helloActor ! "iterate"  
}

a = 0
for (a <- 1 to 3) {
  helloActor ! "add"  
}
a = 0
for (a <- 1 to 10) {
  helloActor ! "iterate"  
}
```

[Scalafiddle link.](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/BymRfcL/8)

**My questions:**

1. Is this how one should create a dynamically changing work buffer inside an akka actor? Perhaps there is a better way to solve this problem?
2. If this isn't the worst idea then what about the implementation. Having an iteratorCounter feels kinda weird to me. Asking for Iterator length moves its pointer. Is there any other way around this?
3. Maybe Manager should not have a changing buffer at all in a worker-pull relationship where worker is capable of spawning new tasks? At the moment I am not capable of seeing any problems with this solution but it is possible that I am not asking the right questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rather than `mutable.ArrayBuffer` and `Iterator`, I would suggest using `immutable.Queue` to queue up work and `enqueue/dequeue` to push/pull work into/from the queue.  From your sample code it appears you're consuming work in a FIFO fashion, hence a queue should best suit your need.
2. I wouldn't recommend using `Iterator` (which is mutable) as a pointer.  In particular, except for `next/hasNext` it's unsafe to use an iterator after calling a method on it (see [Scala doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html)).  With a FIFO queue, iterator won't be needed.
3. It's common to have a manager actor to maintain an internal Queue/Map/etc to keep track of tasks for worker actors.  Whenever applicable, I would pick an immutable collection over mutable collection.  If necessary, make the immutable collection a `private var`, although you can `hot-swap` internal state of an actor via [context.become](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html?language=scala#become-unbecome) if you want to avoid any `var`.

Re: worker systems with a pull model using Akka actors, here is a [nice article](http://letitcrash.com/post/29044669086/balancing-workload-across-nodes-with-akka-2).  There is also a sample app of [distributed worker system](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/akka-distributed-workers) from Lightbend that is based on the pull model.